# Setting up JDBCLoginTimeoutSeconds thru Weblogic Admin Console

Tags: oracle, datasource, weblogic-10.x, connection-timeout

We are facing server hang issue at start up if one of Database not available. I have looked into weblogic documentation and find we can overcome this issue by setting up 'JDBCLoginTimeoutSeconds' property on ServerMBean.

I have googled it and mostly found ways to configure thru code or xml configuration. We don't want to make any code change and do not have direct access to server xml configuration. So just wanted to know if there is a way to setup this property thru Admin Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the WebLogic console, open the datasource configuration. Then on the Connection Pool tab, set the Initial Capacity to 0. This will prevent WebLogic from doing an initial check on the database during startup. The server will start properly even if the database is not available.

Comment: Thanks Brian, This works for us. After changing Initial Capacity, server is able to start even if one or more datasources are unresponsive.